# How to find the number of occurrences of a combination in a list of values

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of number, for example `x <- c(1,3,2,4,2,3,4,4,1,3,2,3,4,1)` and I want to find the number of occurrences of pair (2,3) which in this case is 2. c(1,3,2,4,**2,3**,4,4,1,3,**2,3**,4,1). Or for another example, I want to find the number of occurrences of pair (1,3) which in this case is also 2. c(**1,3**,2,4,2,3,4,4,**1,3**,2,3,4,1). I am wondering what will be the code in R that could solve this case.

I tried to use the table function but it can only show the amount of each value in this list. I expect it to show the occurrence of certain combinations. Like for this instance, it gives me a table look like this.

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(1,3,2,4,2,3,4,4,1,3,2,3,4,1)
y <- lead(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

count(df, x, y)

  x  y n
1 1  3 2
2 1 NA 1
3 2  3 2
4 2  4 1
5 3  2 2
6 3  4 2
7 4  1 2
8 4  2 1
9 4  4 1
```